# Get html body of a httppost

Tags: android, html, forms, http-post

How do I read out html tags from a httppost. the issue is that I have to read out the `__viewstate` key of aspx request and than send them back in a form with user, password. The `get` method is blocked by the server. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, but you could try using Android's `XMLPullParser` to filter out your httppost html tags, then hydrate them into an object, or manipulate them however you like.

Comment: Thanks. Iam thinking about parsing. but how do i get the html code of a httppost?

Comment: Are you doing this within a WebView, or what?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have executed your `HttpPost` you can save the "`response`" inside a `HttpResponse` object.

You can then obtain the HTML from there. Here you can see an example in Java.

```
 HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

 HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("http://any.url.com");

 try{
     HttpResponse response = client.execute(postMethod);
     String yourHTML = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
 }catch(Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

I hope it helps you.